# tximport txidcol and geneidcol selecting wrong column

Tags: r, ensembl, tximport, tx2gene

I'm trying to run a differential expression analysis of 2 samples of the same species, but with different treatments using DESeq2. I'm using Ensembldb to create a tx2gene dataframe for tximport, however tximport does not select the columns I specify, and instead always selects the tx_biotype leading to the following output:

```
.                    25_quant    28_quant
nontranslating_CDS    10422.41    10022.74
protein_coding     22196722.59 24002269.26
```

I'm running tximport using the following params:

```
txi_tx <- tximport(files, type = "salmon", tx2gene = tx2gene,
                   txIdCol = "tx_id", geneIdCol = "gene_id")
```

I've gotten around this by deleting all columns from my tx2gene DF apart from tx_id and gene_id. However, I think this might be causing problems in the DESeq2 analysis somehow, and I would like to rule out that possibility.

This is what my `names(tx2gene)` looks like:

```
"tx_id"            "tx_biotype"       "tx_seq_start"     "tx_seq_end"
"tx_cds_seq_start" "tx_cds_seq_end"  
"gene_id"          "tx_name"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting `type="salmon"` you're overriding your settings for things like `txIdCol`. The various `type` options (except `none`) are presets to set things correctly for the output from various programs like `salmon` or `kallisto`. If you need to specify custom column names, set `type="none"`.

As an aside, if I'm interpreting your question correctly you have only two samples in total. You can not perform a meaningful analysis with an unreplicated experiment, so if that is indeed your case then don't waste your time further with this dataset.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it. As for the lack of replicates this is for an undergraduate research project, and we're just trying to get our R code to work until we get actual data.

Comment: Ah download a public dataset and try to reproduce a published analysis with that. If you can set similarish (or better!) results as those published then you're good to go :)